# Как принудительно установить Linux Mint на SD/USB Flash

Tags: linux-mint, flash-память, live-usb

Проблема в том, что установщик не предлагает выбрать Flash накопитель как целевое устройство. Т.е. если в компе нет винта, то установку просто невозможно продолжить.

Удалось запустить с помощью модификации образа LiveUSB с помощью посторонней тулзы, но это не полноценная установка - просто LiveUSB позволяет сохранять данные, но возможности управления пользователями и софтом сильно ограничены.

Подскажите, что подправить в Лайв образе или как подправить саму флэшку, чтобы установщик воспринимал ее как HDD?

Comment: понятно, что mint — дистрибутив, ориентированный на совсем уж «хомячков», но не может быть, чтобы программу установки извратили до такой степени, чтобы нельзя было установить туда, куда требуется // на шаге выбора целевого устройства наверняка должен быть пункт про «ручную» разбивку.

Comment: Что такое flash? Вы так называете брелок? А с чёго идёт установка? Их у вас два вставлено в компьютер? Архитектура машины Интел? Используется EFI? Там видны эти устройства? Сам брелок качественный? (Это первые вопросы, которые приходят в голову)

Comment: @alexander-barakin если не "хомячок" - проведи эксперимент, найди решение и дай ответ. В вопросе ясно указано - установщик не предлагает других устройств в качестве целевых кроме HDD, соответственно и никаких "ручных" методов с пустотой. Знаешь "нехомячное" решение - предложи

Comment: @0andriy нет, не брелок, а Flash накопитель, и да, их больше, чем один, и да один из них SD-USB, остальные - прямой USB Flash, и да их всех система видит, и таки да - они качественные, использование или неиспользование интерфейса EFI не производит впечатления на установщик.

Comment: @SynCap, OK, я правильно понимаю, что все устройства работают через USB? Возможно ли в установщике выйти в командную строку с правами root? Попробуйте в ней изучить ситуацию с помощью `lsusb`, `gdisk`, `dmesg`. Но мне чего-то интуиция подсказывает, что там скорее всего ПП (поделие поттеринга), и оно виновато в ситуации.

Comment: @0andriy да. Финальная идея - превратить ноут без винта в Linux станцию, работающую с microSD (Linux его видит как USB Flash).

Конечная цель настроить таким образом, чтобы при загрузке монтировался еще один драйв в оперативке, куда копируются и монтируются Home и другие кэши (оперативки - вагон) а при запросе ребута или выключения сбрасываются на карту.

Comment: А у вас ядро установщика поддерживает этот контроллер на этом конкретном ноуте? Вполне может быть, что оно или непатченное, или  старое, или что-то в установщике намутили с */dev/mmcXblkY[pZ]*

Answer (score 3):

ничего исправлять не надо. возможность «ручного» выбора целевого блочного устройства присутствует в программе инсталляции.

---

демонстрация с картинками.

на шаге выбора типа установки надо выбрать последний пункт (в русском переводе — «другой вариант»):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

далее будет диалог с выбором куда ставить систему, и куда ставить загрузчик:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в этот момент я подключил к usb блочное устройство, и чтобы оно отобразилось в диалоге, пришлось вернуться назад и опять выбрать тот же пункт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как видно, я выбрал в качестве целевого вновь появившееся блочное устройство `/dev/sdc` и его же выбрал в качестве цели для установки загрузчика.

далее это устройство надо будет разметить в соответствии с вашими вкусами/потребностями.

Comment: Попробуйте с накопителем SD/MMC. Блочное устройство должно быть вида */dev/mmcblkX*, разделы соответственно */dev/mmcblkXpY*.